# PHP Captcha Image can not be displayed because of errors

Tags: php, captcha

This is my static function in class 'image_utils.php'

```
public static function getCaptcha()
{
     try {
        $width = 200;
        $height = 30;
        $font = 'fonts/arial.ttf';
        //
        if (!file_exists($font)) {
            throw new Exception('Error Font not found');
        }
        //
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $grey = imagecolorallocate($image, 180, 180, 180);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        //
        for ($sq = 1; $sq <= 10; $sq++) {
            $cx = (int)rand(0, $width / 2);
            $cy = (int)rand(0, $height);
            $h = $cy + (int)rand(0, $height / 5);
            $w = $cx + (int)rand($width / 3, $width);
            if (!imagefilledrectangle($image, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, $white)) {
                throw new Exception('Error in White Fill');
            }
        }
        //
        $ellipse_count = 5;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $ellipse_count; $i++) {
            $cx = (int)rand(-1 * ($width / 2), $width + ($width / 2));
            $cy = (int)rand(-1 * ($height / 2), $height + ($height / 2));
            $h = (int)rand($height / 2, 2 * $height);
            $w = (int)rand($width / 2, 2 * $width);
            if (!imageellipse($image, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, $grey)) {
                throw new Exception('Error in Grey Fill');
            }
        }
        //
        imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, 'Captcha');
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        if (!imagepng($image)) {
            throw new Exception('Error in ImagePng');
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Calling it in 'log.php' in img tag:

```
<img src='<?php image_utils::getCaptcha() ?>'/>
```

Gives an error 'The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors'. I have create a check for font file as shown in code so the font file is in inclusion. Please throw some light.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The part of code which throws error with specified error message is missing. Please paste also that code

Comment: @PavelJanicek, that's the complete code. I'm manually catching few errors as shown in code. - Ram Ram

Comment: If you click "show source" on page which should display the image, what URL does that image have?

Comment: Also, I think that root cause might be that your function `getCaptcha()` does not actually ever return any image...